# How do I get around uninitialized global variables in another module in Python?

Tags: python

I have a problem where I'm trying to use a function from another module but that function calls a debug function which checks if a global variable has a certain attribute. This global variable is not set (otherwise set using `parser.parse_args`) when I import the function so the function complains that the attribute doesn't exist. For clarification:

File `findfile.py`:

```
_args = {}

def _debug(msg):
    if _TEST and _args.debug:
        print msg

def findfile(filename):
    ...
    _debug("found file")
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    _args = parser.parse_args()
    ...
```

File `copyafile.py`

```
import findfile

findfile.findfile("file1")
```

This gives me

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'debug'
```

Now I understand that `parser.parse_args()` returns a namespace (??) and that `_args.debug` isn't really looking in the `dict`. But my question is: How can I in this situation properly assign something to `_args` to set the `_args.debug` to `False`?

**I can not change `findfile.py` but I can change `copyafile.py`.**

How are these things usually handled otherwise? What is the pythonic way of enabling debug flags in a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`findfile.py` is wrong as it's written**, but can you try to make it work anyway setting your [`Argumentparser`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/argparse.html#argumentparser-objects) with something like:

```
parser.add_argument('debug', action='store_true')
```

and then with:

```
import findfile
findfile._args = parser.parse_args()
```

have your `_args.debug` set to `False` by default.

About your error:

You get `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'debug'`, beacuse you're trying to access a `dict` like if it was a [`Namespace`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace).

Maybe an example will clarify what a [`Namespace`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) is:

```
>>> d = {'apple': 'red'}
>>> d['apple']
'red'
>>> from argparse import Namespace
>>> ns = Namespace(apple='red')
>>> ns.apple
'red'
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly you want me to create an argument parser in my file and set the _args variable in the other module? I can't change the first file

Comment: `findfile._args = Namespace(debug = False)` did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: @sPirc: I'm sorry that you have to deal with that ugly `findfile.py`, so I guess that any hack is legit. But I'm glad to hear you solved your problem. You might want to accept this answer *(check mark on the left)* :)